# PostgreSQL create partitions of table with existing rows and with referential integrity

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to partitioning a table with existing rows in Postgresql 10.8. 
The structure is like this :
[image]

I'm trying to create partitions of table `Item`, it has around 5mill of rows. 
I create the partitions with those commands:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_1 (CHECK (id >0 AND id <1000001)) INHERITS (item);
CREATE TABLE item_2 (CHECK (id >1000000 AND id <2000001)) INHERITS (item);
...
```

Then the rules:

```sql
 CREATE RULE item_1_rule AS ON INSERT TO item WHERE (id >0 AND id <1000001) DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO item_1 VALUES (NEW.*);
 CREATE RULE item_2_rule AS ON INSERT TO item WHERE (id >1000000 AND id <2000001) DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO item_2 VALUES (NEW.*);
...
```

Then the migration to the partitioned tables:

```sql
INSERT INTO item_1 SELECT * FROM item WHERE (id >0 AND id <1000001);
INSERT INTO item_2 SELECT * FROM item WHERE (id >1000000 AND id <2000001);
...
```

And finally I try to Delete all the rows from the `Item` table:

```sql
DELETE FROM ONLY item;
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR: update or delete on table "item" violates foreign key constraint >"item_audit_item_id_fkey" on table "item_audit"
>   SQL state: 23503
>   Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "item_audit".

So is it possible to drop the data from the *main* table `Item` to have only the rows on the partitions tables? 
There are other alternatives to make a partition in a different way?

Comment: In my opinion, it would be better to upgrade to postgres 12 and use real partitioning with foreign keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use inheritance partitioning, you won't be able to have foreign keys pointing to the partitioned table. You have to drop the constraint before you can delete the rows.

I recommend to use declarative partitioning. If you upgrade to v11 or later, you can have a foreign key pointing to a partitioned table, **but** since the primary key on a partitioned table has to contain the partitioning key, you'd have to add that column to the foreign key as well.

Since partitioning is mostly useful for mass data deletion, it might make sense to partition `item_audit` the same way.

Comment: finally I follow your advice, and I migrate to v12 and use declarative partitioning. I have to add one column 'partition_date' like a primary key and partitioned by range (because I want to partition by years). It works. Thanks a lot. You're a crack in Postgres.